# Shader program isn't used, the drawFrame() function ends up drawing the unfiltered texture

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

This is part of the `MediaExtractor -> MediaCodec (Decoder) -> MediaCodec (Encoder)` workflow. More specifically, the part where the texture from the Decoder's output buffer is rendered into the Encoder's input buffer. For that, I've set up the following `onDrawFrame()` function in the Decoder's output surface:

```
public void drawFrame(SurfaceTexture st) {
    checkGlError("onDrawFrame start");
    st.getTransformMatrix(mPrelimSTMatrix);

    GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    drawToFBO();
}

private void drawToFBO() {
    GLES20.glBindFramebuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
    int mainTextureLoc = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(prelimShaderProgram, "u_Texture");
    checkGlError("glGetMainTextureUniform");

    GLES20.glUseProgram(prelimShaderProgram);
    checkGlError("glUseProgram");
    GLES20.glUniform1i(mainTextureLoc, 0);
    GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, mTextureID);
    checkGlError("glBindTexture");

    onPrelimPreDrawFrame(); //Basically binding the extraneous textures the filter requires

    mTriangleVertices.position(TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_POS_OFFSET);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(maPrelimPositionHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
            TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_STRIDE_BYTES, mTriangleVertices);
    checkGlError("glVertexAttribPointer maPosition");
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(maPrelimPositionHandle);
    checkGlError("glEnableVertexAttribArray maPositionHandle");

    mTriangleVertices.position(TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_UV_OFFSET);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(maPrelimTextureHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
            TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_STRIDE_BYTES, mTriangleVertices);
    checkGlError("glVertexAttribPointer maTextureHandle");
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(maPrelimTextureHandle);

    checkGlError("glEnableVertexAttribArray maTextureHandle");
    Matrix.setIdentityM(mPrelimMVPMatrix, 0);
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(muPrelimMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mPrelimMVPMatrix, 0);
    checkGlError("glmuMVPMatrixHandleSetting");
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(muPrelimSTMatrixHandle, 1, false, mPrelimSTMatrix, 0);
    checkGlError("glmuSTMatrixHandleSetting");

    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
    checkGlError("glDrawArrays");
}

private void createPrelimShader() {
    FRAGMENT_SHADER = VideoUtils.getPrelimFragmentShader(context, prelimFilterCode);
    prelimShaderProgram = createProgram(VERTEX_SHADER, FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    if (prelimShaderProgram == 0) {
        return;
    }
    maPrelimPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(prelimShaderProgram, "aPosition");
    checkGlError("glGetAttribLocation aPosition");
    if (maPrelimPositionHandle == -1) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Could not get attrib location for aPosition");
    }
    maPrelimTextureHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(prelimShaderProgram, "aTexCoordinate");
    checkGlError("glGetAttribLocation aTexCoordinate");
    if (maPrelimTextureHandle == -1) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Could not get attrib location for aTexCoordinate");
    }
    muPrelimMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(prelimShaderProgram, "uMVPMatrix");
    checkGlError("glGetUniformLocation uMVPMatrix");
    if (muPrelimMVPMatrixHandle == -1) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Could not get attrib location for uMVPMatrix");
    }
    muPrelimSTMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(prelimShaderProgram, "uSTMatrix");
    checkGlError("glGetUniformLocation uSTMatrix");
    if (muPrelimSTMatrixHandle == -1) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Could not get attrib location for uSTMatrix");
    }
    filterInputTextureUniform2 = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(prelimShaderProgram, "inputImageTexture2");
    filterInputTextureUniform3 = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(prelimShaderProgram, "inputImageTexture3");
    filterInputTextureUniform4 = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(prelimShaderProgram, "inputImageTexture4");
    filterInputTextureUniform5 = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(prelimShaderProgram, "inputImageTexture5");
    filterInputTextureUniform6 = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(prelimShaderProgram, "inputImageTexture6");
    preloadFilterAssets(VideoUtils.getFilterAssets(prelimFilterCode));

    int[] textures = new int[1];
    GLES20.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);
    checkGlError("glGenFramebuffers");
    mTextureID = textures[0];
    GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES,
            GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
    GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES,
            GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
}
```

The vertex shader looks like this:

```
uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;
uniform mat4 uSTMatrix;
attribute vec4 aPosition;
attribute vec4 aTexCoordinate;
varying vec2 v_TexCoordinate;
void main() {
  gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * aPosition;
  v_TexCoordinate = (uSTMatrix * aTexCoordinate).xy;
}
```

And the fragment shader looks like this, with one extra input texture:

```
#extension GL_OES_EGL_image_external : require
precision lowp float;

varying highp vec2 v_TexCoordinate;

uniform samplerExternalOES u_Texture;
uniform sampler2D inputImageTexture2;

uniform float uParamValue1;

void main()
{
    vec3 texel = texture2D(u_Texture, v_TexCoordinate).rgb;
    vec3 procTexel = vec3(dot(vec3(0.3, 0.6, 0.1), texel));
    procTexel = vec3(texture2D(inputImageTexture2, vec2(procTexel.r, .16666)).r);
    texel += (procTexel - texel) * uParamValue1;
    gl_FragColor = vec4(texel, 1.0);
}
```

None of the `checkGlError()` calls returned any exception, but the video renders as if the texture doesn't go through the OpenGL program created in the `createPrelimShader()` function. It's rendered unfiltered.

On past experience, this is probably caused by something missing in the flow. Is it?

Comment: The *size* of the texture coordinates is probably 2 and not 3: `GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(maPrelimTextureHandle, 2 /* not 3*/, ....);`

Comment: Oh yeah... I forgot about that. It is 2. Though changing that still doesn't have any effect.